# JQuery Disable inputs, when option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 options: `#home-none` and `#home-select`, when #home-none is selected i want all my inputs with class `.home` to be disabled.

HTML:

Options

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option id="home-none">-</option>
    <option id="home-select">Team</option>
</select>
```

Inputs

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control home" name="h-p1-fn" placeholder="First name" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control home" name="h-p1-ln" placeholder="Last name" type="text"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#home-select").click(function(){
            $(".home").prop('disabled',true);
        });
        $("#home-none").click(function(){
            $(".home").prop('disabled',true);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The console doesn't show errors, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're hooking to the wrong event. Use the `change` event of the `select` instead. From there you can read the `value` attribute of the `option` elements to set the relevant `input` elements as disabled. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select.form-control").change(function(){
    $(".home").prop('disabled', $(this).val() == 'home-none');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="home-none">-</option>
    <option value="home-select">Team</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control home" name="h-p1-fn" placeholder="First name" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control home" name="h-p1-ln" placeholder="Last name" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).val() == 'home-none'` should be `$(this).val() == 'home-select'`. inputs are disabled when Team is selected

Comment: Well, that's what your code currently attempts, but your question says: `when #home-none is selected i want all my inputs with class .home to be disabled`. It's confusing. Either way you just need to set the appropriate value in the equality check

Comment: sorry, grammar mistake. u answered the question correctly

Answer (score 2):

This will work better

1. use value instead of ID on option
2. use the change event
3. execute the change event on load to handle a changed select when reloading

Line this:

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option value="home-none">-</option>
  <option value="home-select">Team</option>
</select>

$(function() {
  $("select.form-control").on("change",function() {
    $(".home").prop('disabled',this.value=="home-none");
  }).change(); // execute on load
});
```